# How to do geographical load distribution testing in jmeter for different countries?

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed

My query is here that how can I run my jmeter script just simulating the online scenarios but have the Load distributed between 2 counties like, India and Uk?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to set up slave machines in India and UK and [run your JMeter test in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter).

Alternatively you can [simulate different network bandwidths](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/Controlling+Bandwidth+in+JMeter+to+simulate+different+networks) by manipulating `httpclient.socket.http.cps` and `httpclient.socket.https.cps` [JMeter properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#httpclient_common_properties) but you need to measure the bandwidth for both connections somehow in order to know to what exact value you need to throttle this or that instance.